# Merge sparse questions in multiple columns from questionnaire - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4
   | 2  |    | 
1  |    |    |
   |    | 3  | 
   | 2  |    |
   |    |    | 4
```

My desired output is:

```
Q
_
2
1
3
2
4
```

How can I do it easily in Pandas?

Comment: yes they are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `stack`

```
df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().rename({0:'Q'},axis=1)

    Q
0  2.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
3  2.0
4  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another way to do it

```
df.fillna(method='bfill', axis=1)['Q1'].astype(int).to_frame().rename(columns={'Q1':'Q'})
```

```
    Q
0   2
1   1
2   3
3   2
4   4
```